# Echo text to the user who submitted the form

Tags: php

I have a 2 file PHP script which allows a user to submit a form with a single text area. This script creates a new PHP page and redirects the user to it. I would like to echo text to the user who submitted the form and no one else. Can you help with a code example?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Do you really want it to create a brand new page? or just echo whatever the user typed?

Comment: The script already echos what is typed, I want to echo a support email address only assigned to the new page created.

Comment: Let me make sure i understand this, you want it to create a page on user input, then echo an email address on that newly created page?

Comment: John what I want is a way to send a contact email address to the creator of the page. When others view the page no email will be displayed. The script already works but I can't figure out this last bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me know if this isnt what youre looking for and ill edit it accordingly:

HTML:

```
<input type = "text" name = "input">
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//user input
$userInput = $_POST['input'];

//not sure how you are getting the email adress but however youre getting it it goes here
$email = "placeholder@123.com";

//create the filename
$myFile = $userInput . ".php";

//create the file
$fh= fopen($myFile, 'w');

//write to the file
fwrite($fh, $email);

//redirect to the new file
header("location:". $userInput .".php");
?>
```

basically it creates a new page based off of whatever your user entered and displays an email address to them. I suppose it kind of only allows the user to see it, as it is based off of what they type. other wise the best way to do this would be to store a cookie on the users system (as far as the security goes)